# Spring Di via setter dynamic constructor parameters

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I'm beginner with spring framework, and I'm following [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-di-via-setter-method/) tutorial to applicate DI via setter. All works fine, but I'd like add to my class **CsvOutputGenerator** a constructor with one dynamic parameter, passed on the fly while I getting bean from Application context.

How can I do that?

I've already change my spring configuration in this way:

```
...
<bean id="CsvOutputGenerator" class="com.mkyong.output.impl.CsvOutputGenerator">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="Test"/>
</bean>
...
```

but in this way is static value for my constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it via system property for example

```
<constructor-arg lazy-init="true" type="java.lang.String" value="#{ systemProperties['some.key']}"/>
```

Comment: Do you means from another configuration file? I'd like pass it from my source, when I getting bean from ApplicationContext.

Comment: it sets the properties when it initializes the application context by default, you want lazy initilization and before initialization you need to set system property to pass it in

Comment: Can you make an example of lazy initialization?

Comment: updated in answer, however that seems good idea just to do for learning purpose, if it is real application then better not to stay dependent on such initialization and go for setting property manually by code once it has been initialized

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but there are some class, like as File class, that in their constructor perform some actions - ex: new MyClassFile("mypath"). How do you resolve this cases?

Comment: generally beans are used for services which are accessed from lots of places and most of the time usecase is to use singleton instance of those services, in case of File you can just code to construct instance and manage by yourself, unless there is some `File` instance you want to share across multiple services and you want it to behave like singleton (which I don't think would be the case)

Comment: I've 2 different File class that implements the same interface. Each class have a constructor that expects the filename (String). I want instance one or the other class dynamically. How can I do that?

Comment: dynamically ? please explain

Answer (score 1):

Try something else, even though Spring isn't made to be used like this (note the "prototype" scope):

```
<bean id="CsvOutputGenerator" class="com.mkyong.output.impl.CsvOutputGenerator" scope="prototype" />
```

And then in your code you can do something like this:

```
CsvOutputGenerator myBean = (CsvOutputGenerator) context.getBean("CsvOutputGenerator", "testing testing");
```

[This](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#getBean%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is the method in the API that I used above.

Comment: I followed your instruction, but I obtain this error message: "Cannot resolve method 'getBean(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)'"

Comment: I'd suggest a newer Spring version. Spring right now is at version 4.0.5 the latest, while the tutorial you are testing uses 2.5.6. This version has been released almost 6 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

The below content is based on the above question and comments.
Say u have a class URLRepo with attribute String url. url is initialized to value.
Then you can do something like this, to wire your CsvOutputGenerator

```
public class URLRepo {
     private String url = "your value";
     getters and setters
}


<bean id="urlRepo" class="com.*.*.MyURLRepo"/>    

<bean id="CsvOutputGenerator" class="com.mkyong.output.impl.CsvOutputGenerator">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="urlRepo.url"/>
</bean>
```

hope this is what you are looking for.